# Coloring each face of a Cuboid with a different color

Tags: graphics3d, color

Is there a way to color each face of a `Cuboid` with a different color?

I looked in the help but couldn't find anything.  I found this [Coloring the faces of a 3D object different colors (in Mathematica)](http://forums.wolfram.com/student-support/topics/4054) which proposes building the cuboid with `Polygon` primitives; any other way?

Comment: Since you want to add a color to each face, You really do need each face to be a separate polygon. I don't think there is a better way to accomplish this. What in particular do you wish could be improved upon this approach?

Comment: Nothing special; I just wish to know if there is any other way of doing that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to color the faces of a single cuboid differently (other than the two sides of one face), though there are multiple methods to create multicolored cuboid-like objects.

Creating multiple polygons:

```
v = {{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 
    1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}};
idx = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {2, 3, 7, 6}, {3, 4, 8, 7}, {4, 1, 
    5, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
Graphics3D[Table[{Glow@Hue[i/6], Polygon[v[[idx[[i]]]]]}, {i, 6}], Lighting -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using textures, from the help on [`Texture`](http://wolfram.com/xid/0cg4efice-g0lh2a):

```
sides = Graphics[{Hue@#, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 50] & /@ 
   Most@Range[0, 1, 1/6];
vtc = {{0.01, 0.01}, {0.99, 0.01}, {0.99, 0.99}, {0.01, 0.99}};
Graphics3D[{Black, EdgeForm[Black],
  Table[{Texture[sides[[i]]], 
    GraphicsComplex[v, Polygon[idx[[i]], VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc]]}, {i, 6}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This does nicely and can be easily adapted to other polyhedrons using `PolyhedronData`. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Just for completeness:

```
Graphics3D[{Lighting -> {
    {"Directional", Red, {.5, .5, 1}},
    {"Directional", Green, {1, .5, .5}},
    {"Directional", Blue, {0, 0, 0}}
    },
  Cuboid[]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: cuboid]

Comment: Ingenious. Wouldn't have though ot this. Though it only works if there are no other objects casting a shadow. Cannnot something like `Glow` be used in that case?

Comment: @IstvánZachar there are no shadows in `Graphics3D`!

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yes, silly me. But still adding other objects (like `Cuboid[{1, 1, 1}]`) messes up the colors, so my guess is this method is only applicable when there is only one object in the scene.

Comment: This seems to be less general than the accepted answer, since we can't easily apply `GeometricTransformation` to this: we'll get `Graphics3DBox is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive` error message and no output. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, though...