# How to color specific faces of a polyhedron?

Tags: graphics3d, color, polygons

The following code helps me draw a polyhedron. I would like to color each triangular face in red and make the edges of the polyhedron thicker. I've looked at the  [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13483/coloring-each-face-of-a-cuboid-with-a-different-color), but I'm still not sure how to do it.

```
   Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], FaceForm[Blue], 
       PolyhedronData["SmallRhombicuboctahedron", "Faces"]}], 
     Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step for step:

```
polygons = PolyhedronData["SmallRhombicuboctahedron", "Polygons"];

cor = PolygonCoordinates /@ polygons;
```

Find positions of triangular faces:

```
pos = Flatten @ Position[Length /@ cor, 3]
```

{19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26}

Color them:

```
polygons[[pos]] = {Red, polygons[[pos]]};

Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], FaceForm[
   RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], EdgeForm[{Thickness[Large], GrayLevel[0]}], polygons}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Edit

```
faces = PolyhedronData["SmallRhombicuboctahedron", "Faces"];

faces /. 
  Polygon[pts_] :> 
   Insert [Polygon /@ GatherBy[pts, Length[#] == 3 &], Red, 
    2] // Graphics3D
```

[image]

### Original

We change the strucure of the data of the `PolyhedronData["SmallRhombicuboctahedron", "Faces"]` to get `faces1` and `faces2`

```
faces = PolyhedronData["SmallRhombicuboctahedron", "Faces"];
faces1 = 
 faces /. Polygon[pts_] :> Polygon[Select[pts, Length@# == 3 &]];
faces2 = 
  faces /. Polygon[pts_] :> Polygon[Select[pts, Length@# > 3 &]];
Show[Graphics3D[faces2], Graphics3D[{Red, faces1}], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
t = PolyhedronData["SmallRhombicuboctahedron", "Faces"];
polys = First@Normal@t;
cols = Scan[
      If[Length@MeshPrimitives[#, 1] == 3, Sow@Red, 
        Sow@Lighter@Blue] &, polys] // Reap // Last // First;
edges = Scan[
      If[Length@MeshPrimitives[#, 1] == 3, Sow@Thick, Sow@Thin] &, 
      polys] // Reap // Last // First;
Graphics3D[{
  MapThread[{FaceForm[Opacity[0.7, #1]], EdgeForm[#2], #3} &, {cols, 
    edges, polys}]
  }
 , Boxed -> False
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
styles = FaceForm[Opacity[.5, #]] & /@ {Green, Orange};

PolyhedronData["SmallRhombicuboctahedron", "Graphics3D"] /. 
 p_Polygon :> Map[{styles[[5 - Length @ #]], Polygon @ #} &] @ First @ p
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], FaceForm[Red], 
   EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Green]], 
   PolyhedronData["SmallRhombicuboctahedron", "Faces"]}], 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]